# Convert 4 Div into responsive bootstrap carousel in mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one query regarding how to show 4 boostratp div into a responsive bootstrap carousel slider in small mobile devices only. I have gone through so many website but i am not getting how to actually convert these 4 div elements and show them into a boostrap carousel slider one by one. I will show my code below i need a help to how to convert them into a carousel slider for mobile device only.Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:-

```
<div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center"><span class="nom-pop">Popular</span><span class="bold-treat">Treatments</span></h2>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
            <div class="surgery-wrap clearfix">
                <div class="surgery-icon">
                 <i class="ABCD123-icon ABCD123-cardiology"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-name">
                    <p><strong>Cardiology</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-types">
                    <ul>
                        <li>CABG Surgery</li>
                        <li>Heart Valve Replacement</li>
                        <li>Angioplasty</li>
                        <li>Balloon Angioplasty</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="view-more-surgery">
                    <a href="#" class="vw-more-btn">View More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
            <div class="surgery-wrap clearfix">
                <div class="surgery-icon">
                  <i class="ABCD123-icon ABCD123-orthopedic"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-name">
                    <p><strong>Orthopedics</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-types">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Knee Replacement</li>
                        <li>Hip Replacement</li>
                        <li>ACL Repair</li>
                        <li>Arthoscopy</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="view-more-surgery">
                    <a href="#" class="vw-more-btn">View More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
            <div class="surgery-wrap clearfix">
                <div class="surgery-icon">
                  <i class="ABCD123-icon ABCD123-cosmetic"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-name">
                    <p><strong>Cosmetic</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-types">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Face &amp; Neck Lift</li>
                        <li>Breast Augmentation</li>
                        <li>Mommy Makeover</li>
                        <li>Brazilian Butt Lift</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="view-more-surgery">
                    <a href="#" class="vw-more-btn">View More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
            <div class="surgery-wrap clearfix">
                <div class="surgery-icon">
                     <i class="ABCD123-icon ABCD123-neurology"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-name">
                    <p><strong>Neurology</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="surgery-types">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Brain Tumor</li>
                        <li>Deep Brain Simulation</li>
                        <li>Epilepsy</li>
                        <li>Craniotomy</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="view-more-surgery">
                    <a href="#" class="vw-more-btn">View More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add classes using jquery when using mobile devices and make simple previous and next button to slide using jQuery.

**Update:**
You can use owl [carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) to get the effect.

Comment: Ohhh thanks that's what i was looking for..!! Thank you it works..!